# Can you help me subtract intervals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was reading my abstract math textbook and they subtracted

$[3, 6] - [4, 8) = [3, 4)$. I was wondering if someone could write out how they got to $[3, 4$). I looked at wikipedia and it said I should go 
$[a, b] - [c, d] = [a-d, b-c]$. When I did this, I got $[-5, 2)$. I would be thankful for an explanation-- the book doesn't explain so it's probably really obvious-- but I don't know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure by $-$ the author meant "set minus". So in short $A-B$ indicates the set of elements in $A$ that is not contained in $B$. Some other notations include $A\setminus B$

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at two different definitions of $A-B$:

[Set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Set_difference): $A - B = \{ x\in A \, \mid \, x \notin B \}$ which in this case gives $$[3,6]−[4,8) = [3,4)$$

[Interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic): $A - B = \{ x-y \in \mathbb{R} \, \mid \, x\in A,  \,y \in B \}$ which in this case gives $$[3,6]−[4,8) = (-5,2]$$

Answer (score 0):

$$[3,6]\setminus[4,8)=([3,4)\cup[4,6])\setminus\left([4,6]\cup(6,8)\right)$$
$$=[3,4)\setminus(6,8)$$
$$=[3,4)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be intervals in the real line. Then $I_1 - I_2 = I_1 - (I_1\cap I_2)$.

If $I_1 = [a,b]$ and $I_2 = [c,d]$ (note that $a < b$ and $c < d$) then there are some cases to consider:

If $d < a$ or $b < c$ then $I_1 - I_2 = I_1$ since $I_1\cap I_2 = \emptyset$.

If $a < c < b < d$ then $I_1 - I_2 = [a,c)$ since $I_1\cap I_2 = [c,b]$.

If $c < a < d < b$ then $I_1 - I_2 = (d,b]$ since $I_1\cap I_2 = [a,d]$.

If $a < c < d < b$ then $I_1 - I_2 = [a,c)\cup (d,b]$ since $I_1\cap I_2 = I_2$.

If $c < a < b < d$ then $I_1 - I_2 = \emptyset$ since $I_1\cap I_2 = I_1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same like sets. Not subtracting intervals.

So we want to find the values that exists in $[3,4]$ but don't exists in $[4,8]$. It should be very clear how the author got $[3,4)$

notice that the answer is open at $4$ so $4$ itself is not included since $ 4\in [4,8]$